# What is more efficient: writing to disk or message passing a huge amount of data as an array between a Python node and CPP node?

Tags: ros, communication, messages

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Does anyone have experience with the following scenario:

A *Python node* that needs to pass a large amount of float values (an array of images) as a multidimensional `numpy array` to a *CPP node*.

**The dilemma:** What is better (in terms of memory or speed):

**a)** To pass the data as a serialized `float32[]` message array between these nodes?

**b)** To write the data to a binary file and just communicate the file's location as a `string` msg?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/246692/what-is-more-efficient:-writing-to-disk-or-message-passing-a-huge-amount-of-data-as-an-array-between-a-python-node-and-cpp-node?/) by [ubuntuslave](https://answers.ros.org/users/631/ubuntuslave/) on ROS Answers with karma: 347 on 2016-10-28

Post score: 2

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) on 2016-10-29**:
Can you quantify *huge*?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Sending data as a message (ie memory copies) is significantly faster than writing it to disk.

Have a look at these [latency numbers](https://gist.github.com/jboner/2841832) for a comparison of the speed of different operations, and remember that ROS message passing (network traffic) between different nodes **on the same computer** is actually just a memory copy, and never uses the network hardware.

---

Originally posted by [ahendrix](https://answers.ros.org/users/1034/ahendrix/) with karma: 47576 on 2016-10-28

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 3

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [ubuntuslave](https://answers.ros.org/users/631/ubuntuslave/) on 2017-02-14**:
My message size is an array (i.e. `float32[]` of about `648*480*300` or `93312000` elements or `355 MB` size). I noticed that writing/reading the array to/from disk takes less time than passing it via a ROS Service. Anyways to speed up the message passing? It takes 5 seconds now to receive the msg.

**Comment by [ubuntuslave](https://answers.ros.org/users/631/ubuntuslave/) on 2017-02-14**:
I would like to note that this slow performance happens even when the service client is set to be **persistent**.

**Comment by [ahendrix](https://answers.ros.org/users/1034/ahendrix/) on 2017-02-15**:
I'd expect python would take a while to serialize python datatypes, but I wouldn't think it would take 5 seconds to serialize that much data using the optimized numpy methods.